# Java can't find class named 'and'? --Not standard class not found exception--

Tags: java, classpath

I know there are a thousand java can't find a class questions, but this one really seems weird and not like the standard type.

This is the exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
```

I have no idea whats going on because it is looking for a class named 'and'. First this is non capitalized and supposedly a class name, and second it is showing up in the standard package, which I don't really use. So to me it looks like something else is the problem, but I can't figure it out. I had someone else look at it and they were lost too, so if someone could provide some insight, then that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Update: Here is the error message that pops up when I try to run the launch.

[image]

Comment: Can we see your code around where this is happening?

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of code?  Are you explicitly using the URLClassloader?

Comment: There is a launch configuration that I am supposed to be running and that is where the problem is, so I don't know what snippet of code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you are providing the full path to your My Documents to the command line aren't you?

the problem is that the path to your `My Documents` folder has `C:\Documents and Settings` in it and the command line delimits arguments by whitespace and is interpreting this as separate arguments instead of part of a path

and the first argument of `java` without a leading `-` is taken as the class name where the main function is

if you are using commandline enclose the paths in `"`: `"C:\Documents and Settings\hbtest\My Documents\path to folder"`

Comment: @amir it's a rather common problem with command line tools (or anything that handles spaces specially) combined with windows file paths pointing to `My Documents` or `Program Files`

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't seem to be working. Your suggestion seems like an excellent one, and a likely source of problem, but not solving my issue.

Comment: @hb I'll need to know more about how you are running it to help any further

Comment: Is there someway I can see a list of the classes that my program is trying to load before it gets loaded? Or where would I look for list of classes being passed in? I know there is the VM args in the run configuration, but Im looking for something like a logger

Comment: @hb I'll need to know what you are using to try and launch it (IDE you are using, settings of it,  libraries you are using things like that)

Comment: Ok. The thing is, im doing dev for a company, so I am a little hesitant to post details of that work online. If i can get nowhere after looking in the places you pointed me (examining class path) then I might have no other choice.

Comment: So I guess you were right, or somethign similar to what you said. I moved my workspace to C:\workspace and it worked